# the Verlinde formula

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, model-categories

The [Verlinde formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlinde_algebra) writes the fusion coefficient in terms of S matrix. My question is that for fusion category without braiding, is there a similar formula which gives the fusion coefficient in terms of F symbols?